# Open python script in a new terminal tab [Linux/Bash/Python]

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, script, python

I have lots of servers written in `Python`. I want to run them, one script per one terminal tab. I'm using `Xubuntu 16.04`.

I know how to open the terminal tab in Xubuntu inside the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-terminal --tab
```

Also, I know how to run python script in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python server_1.py
```

But how can I open a new tab, and run the script in this new, opened tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the -x and -e options, have you tried them?

```
-x, --execute
    Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal
-e, --command=command
    Execute command inside the terminal
```

Ie. something like:

```
xfce4-terminal --tab --execute python server_1.py
```

If there is a problem with the skript path, you can specify the working directory with:

```
--working-directory=directory
```

Comment: I have weird errors when trying the `--working-directory=directory` (terminal has closed immediately) but the `-x` option works. Thank you for help.